# Using the output of a Nextflow process as the input of another process in DSL2

Tags: nextflow

I am having a bit of a hard time grasping how the organization of channels and inputs and outputs works while passing an output of a process to an input.

Say I have a tuple of /some/path/to/filepair{1,2}.fasta.gz and I want to copy them to a different location in one process, then pass that along to the next process to unzip them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

reads_ch=Channel.fromPath('/some/path/to/filepair{1,2}.fastq.gz')
workflow {
  doMove(reads_ch)
  doUnzip(doMove.out)
}

process doMove {
  input: 
    path reads_ch
    
  output:
    path(moved)
  script:
    
    
    """
    cp '${filepairs}' /some/new/path/
    """
    
}

process doUnzip {
  input: 
    path(moved)
    
  output:
    stdout
  script:
    
    
    """
    gunzip $moved
    """
    
}
```

This results in the following error

```
Error executing process > 'doMove (21)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `moved` expected by process `doMove (21)`

Command executed:

  cp '/some/path/to/filepair1.fastq.gz' /some/new/path/

Command exit status:
  0

Command output:
  (empty)

Work dir:
  /some/new/path/work/ce/f93032ae5ac36481e4452440440eab

Tip: you can replicate the issue by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `bash .command.run`
```

Answer (score 0):

The output `path` you've supplied doesn't exist. You need to supply an actual path. In your case something like `path(/some/new/path/*.fastq.gz)`.

However, in this case this would be a bit messy since you'd be emitting each of the files in the directory individually to the next process.

If you use the [fromFilePairs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromfilepairs) method to read in files, it will automatically assign sample IDs from the name. See documentation in link.

So using `reads_ch=Channel.fromFilePairs('/some/path/to/filepair{1,2}.fastq.gz')` would create a tuple that looks something like `[filepair, [filepair1.fastq.gz, filepair2.fastq.gz]]`, and your `doMove` process would look something like this if you wanted to handle both input and output tuples. I've also added a tag which makes following which samples are being processed easier.

```
process doMove {
  tag "$sample_id"
  input: 
    tuple val(sample_id), path(read)
    
  output:
    set val("$sample_id"), path("output/*")

  script:
    """
    mkdir output
    mv ${reads} output
    """
    
}
```

Just to be clear, files are all staged in the work directory and are usually moved as symlinks between process specific work directories unless specified otherwise. So a process that only moves files doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you! For clarification, the input files are in a separate drive that has been configured so that the files in it cannot be altered in any way, that's why my first thought was to copy the files locally to unzip them.

Comment: You don't need to copy the files locally. Once nextflow stages the files they should be able to modify them. So your first process could be unzipping them as well as some processing.